# objective-c++ Confusion

Tags: iphone, xcode, objective-c++

I have several small questions of what can be done in objective-c++

I'm trying to port something, I would love if someone could answer me

Let's say I have this class

a.h

```
    class bedInfoLayer : public Layer
{
public:
    a() { bclass = [[b alloc] init]; }
private:
    b* bclass;


};
```

and I have this

b.h

```
@interface b {
    a *ainstance;
}
@end

@implementation b
- (id)init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        ainstance = new a();
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

I hope someone could help me and point out what can be done and what not, the second one most properly is going to work, but am afraid of the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the code doesn't release memory properly. But in Objective C++ it's totally legitimate for C++ to allocate Objective-C objects, and vice-versa.

Comment: Hi I couldn't do what's done in a.h, could you confirm, is there any special settings, thanks

Comment: Objective-C++ must be enabled explicitly in the project settings, but that's it.

Comment: Thanks, changed implementation file from .cpp to .mm, now that works, thanks, this will save huge time :)

Comment: Also, be sure to release objects when you are done with them.

Comment: LOL, yeah don't worry It was just an example, :D